# How to refer to a record in a table without a primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have created a table without any primary key and it contains some exactly identical records.
How do I update or view a record using SQL statements?

The structure of my table is like :-

```
+----------------+-------+---------+----------+
| Name           | class | section | City     |
+----------------+-------+---------+----------+
| Mohit Yadav    |    10 | A       | Neemrana |
| Mohit Yadav    |    10 | A       | Neemrana |
| Janvi Yadav    |    10 | A       | Neemrana |
| Jaspreet Singh |    11 | B       | Jaipur   |
| Jaspreet Singh |    11 | B       | NULL     |
+----------------+-------+---------+----------+
```

Can we refer to the second record and change the class to 11th using update command.
Something like this would work:-

`UPDATE <SOMETBL> SET CLASS='11' WHERE {INDEX_OF_RECORD=1};`

Please rectify the part written inside the curly brackets so that I can refer to a record using its index.

Comment: There is no concept of a "Nth record" in a table.  You must use data to specify the row, and hope that it is specific enough.

Comment: In an RDBMS, a table without a PRIMARY KEY isn't really a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, not having a primary key is not a good idea at all, it is always a good practice to have the so-called `ID` column. But as it is the case now, there would be some ways.

The first and second records are exactly identical, as you said. So there is no actual difference between them to distinguish. So it doesn't matter at all to change the first row or the second one, and a good approach to achieve so is to put limitation on number of rows the update query affect on. you can simply use this

```
UPDATE <SOMETBL> SET CLASS='11' WHERE
    NAME ='Mohit Yadav' AND
    CLASS ='10' AND
    SECTION ='A' AND
    CITY ='Neemrana'
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I inspected your code and thought that there was no proper way of doing it, rather it was sort of a hack. But there is one drawback that we could not update the info in the record with sr. no 2. But since they are exactly the same, it's not practically benificial. However, it worked. Thanks, bud.

Comment: @SnazzyMohit yw

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to add an auto incrementing column and then refer to the record by its now unique int:

```
ALTER TABLE `t` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```